# Some clients are unable to load SQLite.Interop.dll

Tags: c#, sqlite

There is an application that uses SQLite. Link to System.Data.SQLite and SQLite.Interop.dll (for x64 and x86 platforms) added statically, version 1.0.112.0. (all 3 files) (SQLite was added to the test project via NuGet, and from there copied to the current project). The System.Data.SQLite and SQLite.Interop.dll files (in the x86 and x64 folders) are present on the client machine. .Net version is 4.7.2.

Most clients work fine, but a few throw an exception with the text "Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'". I build test versions for x86 and x64 on my machine, in each case SQLite.Interop.dll was loaded from the corresponding folder (If SQLite.Interop.dll does not exist on the corresponding path, then there was an exception).

Where to look to avoid this exception on all client machines?

There is a hunch that the client is missing Microsoft Visual C ++ Redistributable. But later I find out that Redistributable was installed.

The next assumption is that the system can find SQLite.Interop.dll, but an error occurs during loading or initialization, which is interpreted by the wrapper(System.Data.SQLite) as DllNotFoundException.

Comment: You can use the [Assembly Binding Low Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) to verify that the DLL is actually being loaded from the correct location and go on from there. Using the DependencyWalker might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, the cause of the DllNotFoundException was found. This is because SQLite.Interop.dll has a dependency on msvcr120. (Dependency Walker was used to figure this out). But there is one small thing, if the application is for the x64 platform, then this file is expected to be found in the C:\Windows\System32 folder. But if the platform is x86, then the file should be on the path C:\Windows\SysWOW64. I saw that msvcr120 is in the System32 folder and decided that problem is not related to msvcr120.

The simplest solution is to build the application for the x86 platform, and place the msvcr120 next to the exe-file.

I found a better solution to the problem. The corresponding version of msvcr120 is located next to SQLite.Interop.dll in the x86 or x64 folder. Before using sqlite (for example, in the Application constructor or in its overloaded OnStartup() method) we need to add our folder to the PATH environment variable.

```
var pathVar = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
       
string customDllFolder;
if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
{
    customDllFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "x64");
}
else
{
    customDllFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "x86");
}

pathVar = string.Concat(pathVar, ";", customDllFolder);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", pathVar, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

This solution is better because we will only use a local copy of msvcr120 if it is not on the user's machine. We can also build an application for both platforms (x86 and x64). This approach can be used for other unmanaged libraries as well.

Comment: MSVCR120 is part of Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013. You should bundle the x64 and x86 version installer with your app installer to prevent such cases.

Comment: @webmaster442, I work with it. I need a way to load MSVCR120 from custom folder, if it does not exist on user machine. I try SetDllDirectory(), but it does not work. I work with it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the path pointing to the dll is too long?

We had a similar problem when the path that pointed to the dll was too long (More than 255 chars).

Comment: Dll is near exe-file. If path will be too long then app can not be started. Also I check path on client machine, and it less then 255 chars. But your idea is pretty good.